# Apache Derby simplified usage

Tags: java, derby

I'm using apache derby in a project and no problems so far. But writing all the sql statements, defining the names of the columns and so on is very time consuming. I tried to abstract the sql statements in a way but I'm sure I'm not the first one who tried to simplified the usage with derby.

Does anyboby know, is there a framework or something similar which one can use on top of derby?
Or should I try an approach with reflections, in which for example the fields of a class were automatically used as columns of a table? And also if one defines methods in that class in a predefined manner, the code for the sql statements is automatically generated. I never used reflections so I'm not sure if I have a wrong idea what one could achieve with reflections.

Thanks in advance for any helpful hint concering this.

Comment: Like Hibernate? It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm really unexperienced with databases, sql and so on, so I'm maybe not really able to ask the correct question. I never heard about Hibernate, I will check this, maybe I could then rewrite my question to make clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, Hibernate looks like what I was looking for. So If you maybe put your comment to an answer I could mark it as accept? Any suggestions how to edit my question to make it more clear for other people who are looking for the same?

Comment: Well, requests for libraries etc. are generally consider OT for SO. The phrase you're looking for is ORM, Object Relational Mapper. There are multiple options in this space, though, which turns it into either a list of options (OT) or opinion-based (also OT :)

Comment: Hibernate is called an "Object Relational Mapper" - it makes very easy things easy, hard things hard, and the complex stuff impossible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So you would not recommend using an ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is an ORM, an Object-Relational Mapper.

This allows convenient transformation between data in a variety of databases and the object models actually used by your code.

Hibernate is an implementation of JPA (Java Persistence API) that is widely used, but there are others.